# Adding new values to existing keys of nsuserdefault using nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I am finding some problem while saving and retrieving data using nsuserdefaults.
What i want to do- iam accepting name and number from user from viewcontroller and saving it using nsuserdefault. when i click on save button i want to retrieve all the values from nsuserdefault and display it on tableview. now when i save the new data i want this data to get added to the existing data of nsuserdefault. can anyone help me with saving and retrieving nsuserdefault data.
----------MyCode---------------

```
nsuserdefaults *objdefault =[nsuserdefaults standarduserdefaults];
nameArray = [objdefault objectforkey:@"Name"];
[newNameArray addobject:txtName.text];
[nameArray addobject:newNameArray];
[objdefault setobject:nameArray forkey:@"Name"];
[objdefault synchronize];
```

all this saves and accepts null value
Please help. and thank you in advance

Comment: You should not be storing data in `NSUserDefaults`. As the name implies, you should only be storing user defaults. Actual data should be written to a file. In your case, write the array to a file using `writeToFile:`.

Comment: I'll have to try this. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use these methods to add name to `NSUserDefaults`and get from `NSUserDefaults`
To add the `name` to  `NSUserDefaults` call `[self addNameToUserDefaults:@"abc"];`

```
-(void)addNameToUserDefaults:(NSString *)name number:(NSString*)number{
    NSUserDefaults *objdefault =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *nameArray = [[objdefault objectForKey:@"NameAndNumber"] mutableCopy];

    if(!nameArray)
        nameArray = [@[] mutableCopy];
    [nameArray addObject:@{@"name":name,@"number":number}];

    [objdefault setObject:nameArray forKey:@"NameAndNumber"];

    [objdefault synchronize];


}
```

To get all `names` from  `NSUserDefaults` call `NSMutableArray *names = [self getAllNames];`

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getAllNames{

    NSUserDefaults *objdefault =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    return [[objdefault objectForKey:@"NameAndNumber"] mutableCopy];

}
```

Comment: hey @codester ,  tried doing as you had directed. but i cannot store more than one value for each of my key namely name and number. is there any other possibility.

Comment: You can use `NSDictionary` and save data in NSDictionary

Comment: You can find the same `NSDictionary` from array by using `name` or `number`

Comment: edited my answer.Please check.It will solve your problem

Comment: i tried using nsdictionary still cannot save values

Comment: i tried it by adding dictionary object into an array. this is only creating array within an array but is storing the recent entered value

Comment: This answer will fail because NSUserDefaults won't return a `NSMutableArray`, just an `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add values for same in NSUSerDefaults. it will show you last value only. You should go for Core data or Sqlite. Still if you are not comfortable with that you can use plist to achieve this functionality.

Comment: previously i had tried sving more than one value for the key name. which was a success but couldnt retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done in my project. You have to use NSMutableDictionary to add more value

```
- (void)addUserLocation:(NSString *)username location:(NSMutableDictionary *)location
{
    NSString *currentUserKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", UserDefaultsKeyLocationData, username, nil];
    NSMutableArray *oldData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if ([self loadUserLocation:username] != nil) {
        oldData = [self loadUserLocation:username];
    }

    if (![oldData containsObject:location]) {
        [oldData addObject:location];
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:oldData forKey:currentUserKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)loadUserLocation:(NSString *)username
{
    NSString *currentUserKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", UserDefaultsKeyLocationData, username, nil];

    return [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:currentUserKey] mutableCopy];
}
```

If you want get all data. Please call loadUserLocation in your code